# prove that a map $g: M \to N$ is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix (that is, the columns of $A$ are perpendicular to one another and have length $1$). Then multiplication by $A$  defines a map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, which restricts to a map $ f|_{S^{n-1}} := g:S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$. Prove that $g$ is smooth.

It is not difficult to show that image of the restriction of $f$ is $S^{n-1}$.

I know that to prove that a map $g: M \to N$  is smooth, I need to find two charts $(X,u)$ and $(Y,v)$ in the respective atlases of $M$ and $N$, such that $X^{-1}\circ \ g \ \circ \ Y$ be smooth. As $X$ and $Y$, I used stereographic charts from $S^{n-1}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, but it turns out that the composition $X^{-1}\circ \ g \ \circ \ Y$ is not smooth at several points...

*My calculations*

Let $\psi_N : S^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be the stereographic projection, with the formulas $$\psi_N ( x_1 ,..., x_n ) =  ( \frac{x_1}{1- x_{n} },\frac{x_2}{1- x_{n} },...,\frac{x_{n-1}}{1- x_{n} } )$$ And $$\psi^{-1}_N ( y_1 ,..., y_{n-1} ) =  ( \frac{2y_1}{y^2_1 + y^2_2 + ... + y^2_{n-1} +1 },\frac{2y_2}{y^2_1 + y^2_2 + ... + y^2_{n-1} +1 },...,\frac{2y_{n-1}}{y^2_1 + y^2_2 + ... + y^2_{n-1} +1 },\frac{y^2_1 + y^2_2 + ... + y^2_{n-1} -1}{y^2_1 + y^2_2 + ... + y^2_{n-1} +1 } )$$ $A=(a_{ij})$, $\beta_k=\frac{2y_{k}}{y^2_1 + y^2_2 + ... + y^2_{n-1} +1 } \ \ \ (1\leq k \leq n-1)$ and $\beta_n=\frac{y^2_1 + y^2_2 + ... + y^2_{n-1} -1}{y^2_1 + y^2_2 + ... + y^2_{n-1} +1 }$ Now computations regarding $ \psi_N \circ \ g \ \circ \ \psi^{-1}_N$ leads to $$ \psi_N \circ \ g \ \circ \ \psi^{-1}_N ( y_1 ,..., y_{n-1} ) = \left( \frac{\sum^n_{i=1} a_{1i}\beta_i}{1-\sum^n_{i=1} a_{ni}\beta_i},\frac{\sum^n_{i=1} a_{2i}\beta_i}{1-\sum^n_{i=1} a_{ni}\beta_i}, ... , \frac{\sum^n_{i=1} a_{(n-1)i}\beta_i}{1-\sum^n_{i=1} a_{ni}\beta_i} \right)$$
Is this the standard approach ? Can I use something else instead of stereographic charts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f=g\circ{i}$ and $i:S^{n-1}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}^n$ is smooth.

Comment: @gaoxinge Domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R^n}$ but the domain of $g \ o \  i$ is $S^{n-1}$, do you mean $g=f \ o \ i $ , that does not work again

Comment: E... You are right.@the8thone

Comment: The composition $X^{-1}\circ g\circ Y$ (or should it be $X\circ g \circ Y^{-1}$?) will be smooth at all points where it's defined.  Could you say a bit more/ show some calculations as to why you think its not smooth at several points?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I'm gonna add my calculations

Comment: @the8thone:  Well, I hope I'm not causing you too much work - sometimes these kind of calculations can get really messy.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but, pick $x\in S^n$ with $x$ and $f(x)$ both distinct from the north pole.  The composition is smooth unless $1-\sum a_{ni}\beta_i = 0$, or equivalently, that $1 = \vec{a_n} \cdot\vec{x}$ where $\vec{a_n}$ is the last row of the matrix and $\vec{x}$ is the point on the sphere.  By the dot product formula, we have $1 = |\vec{a_n}||\vec{x}|\cos\theta = \cos \theta$ so $\theta = 0$, i.e., $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{a}$ are the same vector.  Since the other rows of the matrix are orthogonal to $\vec}{a}_n, it follows that $\vec{a_i}\cdot \vec{x} = 0.$

Comment: Said another way, this says that $f(x)$ is the north pole, contrary to our original hypothesis.  If either $x$ or $f(x)$ is the north pole, then at least one of the charts must be changed to stereographic projection from the south pole instead of the north pole.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you very much, I appreciate it

Comment: @the8thone:  Glad I could help!  If you'd like, you could write up an answer to the problem yourself (including a lot more details).

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
g = \operatorname{inc} \circ f \circ \operatorname{inc}
$$
where
$$
 \operatorname{inc}: S^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb R^n
$$
is the inclusion. Since $F:=f\circ \operatorname{inc}$ is smooth (a composition), so you must show the following little theorem:

If $F:N \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is smooth and $F(N) \subseteq S^{n-1}$, then $\operatorname{inc} \circ F$ is smooth.

(do you know what an embedded or regular submanifold is?)

Hint: formula for $\psi_n$ is defined on $U:=\{x_n<1\} \subseteq \mathbb R^n$

so $\Psi_N:U \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, $\Psi_N(x):=(\psi_N,x_n)$ is a well defined map. Compute the derivative, inverse function theorem, local diffeomorphism,...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that seems to be a very clean approach, but this question is asked right after manifolds are defined, we have not got to the definnition of embedded submanifolds yet...